# Fullscreen VideoView isn't Centered

Tags: android

I use this XML layout to show a fullscreen VideoView on my activity. The Video is fullscreen but it isn't centered. In landscape mode, it stays on the left side of the screen and leaves some blank spaces on the right side of the screen.

How can I make my VideoView placed in the center of the screen?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293909/surfaceview-height-width-gets-ignored/20798009#20798009) hope it works for u.
make layout as andro said but with fill parent instead of wrap content.

Answer (score 11):

Try this layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"              
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:gravity="center">



         <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoview"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: there's no orientation on a `RelativeLayout`, but this worked for me! it should be accepted as the correct answer

Comment: It doesn't work on portrait. I see the video aligned to the top of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    </VideoView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work on portrait. I see the video on the top of the screen.

Answer (score -1):

If your VideoView cannot center in RelativeLayout you can try to put it into a FrameLayout like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </VideoView>

</FrameLayout>
```

And then put this into RelativeLayout.

Comment: It doesn't work on portrait. I still see the video aligned to the top of the screen.