# Center video at center of screen - Videoview Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview

I have a video view, that plays a certain video this is his xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



Some other views


    <VideoView
        android:id = "@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying to center the video in it, yet when ever I play the video,
It does not appear at the center, and the location changes a bit depends on the video, how do you center it?

Comment: Try `android:layout_centerInParent="true` in `Video View`.

Comment: not working this didnt help

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518283/fullscreen-videoview-isnt-centered

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @jaydroider told, you could use layout_centerInParent=true

In this example, i changed width and height and changed background color of main layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Don't use** *android:layout_alignParentTop="true"* and *android:layout_alignParentStart="true"* because if you use it, layout always showing at TOP/LEFT position

Answer (score 0):

In my case I only had to use `android:layout_gravity="center"` to center the actual VideoView to the center