# Video view is not full screen in landscape mode

Tags: android, xml, landscape

I am using a video view designed with xml. This video is full screen in Portrait mode but when it turns to the landscape mode, it is left aligned and both width and height are wrapped instead of full screen.

I referred these, but still no solution for this.

[Fullscreen VideoView isn't Centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518283/fullscreen-videoview-isnt-centered)

[Android-Video View in Fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776254/android-video-view-in-fullscreen)

Any one knows the answer for this?

**Update:** Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<VideoView android:id="@+id/youtubewebView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_gravity="fill" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update 2:**

```
public class VideoStreamingActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.your_video_view);
    String videoUrl = "http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp";
    try {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoView.requestFocus();
    //videoView.start();
    videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            videoView.start();
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "restart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "resume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onResume();
}
```

}

Comment: @AndroSelva, can you see my xml?

Comment: did u test it with only height and width set to fill parent?

Comment: no, all methods I tried. I mean match parent property and even hard coded height and width. Still then it is wrapped.

Comment: just to confirm, does the video view doesn't fit while playing video or it just doesn't fit in the graphical layout thing itself, that is, when you designed it?

Comment: while playing it is not fitting. When I looked with graphical layout, I can see it as filled

Comment: is it possible to give the link of the video. I might give it a try?

Comment: sure, this is a sample video http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp

Comment: try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293909/surfaceview-height-width-gets-ignored/20798009#20798009) hope it works for u.

Answer (score 33):

Are you sure that it is not filling up the screen. it works fine for me. Here is the xml file,

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**onCreate()**

```
VideoView video=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
    video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp"));
    video.start();
}
```

**ScreenShot for Portrait mode**

[image]

**Screenshot for Landscape Mode**

[image]

Comment: oh this is working for you, yes I am 150% sure it was not working. Wait I will try this

Comment: Still same, it will be full screen initially in the portrait mode. When I do landscape it loses it and aligned to the left. Now when I turn it back to portrait even portrait is not full screen height wise

Comment: And my oncreate is like this, videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();

Comment: Your code is working in a way, but are you able to get the controls there? I am referring to play/pause, and FF/Rw buttons. I am not getting and when I rotate the screen, it again starts streaming from the first

Comment: You have to make use of MediaController for that.It works like a popup at the bottom of the screen by default and overlaps over VideoView. So there shud be no problem. And to play video continuously you have to override the onResume() and onPause().

Comment: Yes, finally it is full screen now. But I have one more issue here of streaming from first now. I have updated my question with the code. Please check it. It again comes to oncreate and thereafter follows the  normal procedure. How to avoid this

Comment: sorry I cudn't get ur question? Can u elaborate it in your question?

Comment: I said it is full screen now. But regarding orientation wise,it starts streaming, say now it is in portrait mode. But when I change it to the landscape mode it again starts streaming from the first. That means again it is parsing the url. How to avoid this

Comment: try adding this line to ur activity in manifest android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Comment: Hello, I am facing bit weird issue, Create simple media player supported with surface view. It support both Portrait and Landscape. But same is not working in Galaxy and HTC 1 mob...any idea/suggestion why it is so..?

Comment: @AndroSelva Thanks, this answer is working for me, but what can be done if multiple videos have multiple resolutions? Your current solution stretches some video.

Comment: @tejas  u got solution i m also facing same issue it starts streaming again from the first