# Fullscreen VideoView in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-fullscreen, android-videoview

I wish to make VideoView into full screen in landscape mode. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027216/video-view-is-not-full-screen-in-landscape-mode). It shows a margin from left and right. I want to know how I can make the VideoView fullscreen.

My .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoViewN"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may add theme to the activity in manifest file:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

And for VideoView in xml, change

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

This will help you achieve fullscreen in video view. Hope it helps.

Comment: @RahulMatte have you added `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in manifest as well?

Comment: I am forcing activity to open only in Landscape mode...so I think i don't need

Comment: Ok. Try adding `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);` these two lines before `setContentView`. @RahulMatte

Comment: ok..Already I have this lines after setContentView getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager
    .LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Comment: @RahulMatte Can you check if that works before setContentView?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55555/discussion-between-rahul-matte-and-little-suzy).

Answer (score 1):

adding below codes before setContentView works for me in onCreate function. I hope it helps.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: ok...I come to know that videoview display the resolution according to source file resolution...Ok. But Can I stretch it to full screen..I tried your code for me it's not working

Comment: it is better to save the aspect ratio, anyway using below properties may help you.  android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:layout_weighht="fill_parent"

Answer (score 1):

**Full Screen Landscape Video**

AndroidManifext.xml (Setting the orientation)

```
        <activity
        android:name=".Video1"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Video1.xml Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Video1">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
</VideoView>
```

Video1.java Code :

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Video1 extends AppCompatActivity {

private VideoView videoView;
private MediaController mediaController;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video1);

    videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    String fullScreen =  getIntent().getStringExtra("fullScreenInd");
    if("y".equals(fullScreen)){
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }

    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.YOUR_VIDEO_NAME);

    videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

    mediaController = new FullScreenMediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.start();
    }
}
```

FullScreenMediaControler.java Code :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.MediaController;

public class FullScreenMediaController extends MediaController {

private ImageButton fullScreen;
private String isFullScreen;

public FullScreenMediaController(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void setAnchorView(View view) {

    super.setAnchorView(view);

    //image button for full screen to be added to media controller
    fullScreen = new ImageButton (super.getContext());

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    params.rightMargin = 80;
    addView(fullScreen, params);

    //fullscreen indicator from intent
    isFullScreen =  ((Activity)getContext()).getIntent().
            getStringExtra("fullScreenInd");

    if("y".equals(isFullScreen)){
        fullScreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_exit);
    }else{
        fullScreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fullscreen);
    }

    //add listener to image button to handle full screen and exit full screen events
    fullScreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Video1.class);

            if("y".equals(isFullScreen)){
                intent.putExtra("fullScreenInd", "");
            }else{
                intent.putExtra("fullScreenInd", "y");
            }
            ((Activity)getContext()).startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
  }
}
```