# android how to resize video width and height in surface view for media player

Tags: android, android-layout, android-video-player

**Want to resize the video in surface view**

I am Playing a video in Media Player with using a Surface view and holder for video...

*// but on implementing MediaPlayerControl on some devices say Micromax, iball, Akash tablet it gives error of abstract method not available as tracked by ACRA bug tracking.*

Now I want to have solution of mentioned problems:

- How to get media player controls active in all devices wihtout crashing due to abstract method as for media controller in some
  devices.
- How can I resize the surface view of video.

The code is working f9 on **samsung galaxy gt p1000 OS 2.2** and some cheaper device WorldTeck etc.

But on **Creative ziio 7 OS version is 2.2.1 (480*800)** **resolution density is 160 dpi** video seems to be zoomed and gets cutt off from the edges.

The code is shown below:

```
/* Media Player Control is commented due to force close in some devices say *micromax,Creative ziio, akash etc */

    public class VideoViewerActivity extends Activity implements
            OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener,
            OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        // implements  ERROR in some devices , MediaPlayerControl
        private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayerDemo";
        private int mVideoWidth;
        private int mVideoHeight;
        private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
        private SurfaceView mPreview;
        private SurfaceHolder holder;
        private String path = "";
        private Bundle extras;
        private static final String MEDIA = "media";
        private static final int LOCAL_AUDIO = 1;
        private static final int STREAM_AUDIO = 2;
        private static final int RESOURCES_AUDIO = 3;
        private static final int LOCAL_VIDEO = 4;
        private static final int STREAM_VIDEO = 5;
        private boolean mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
        private boolean mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
        /* ERROR In Abstract method implementation in the other devices */
        // private MediaController mediaController;
        private Context context;
        private final Handler handler = new Handler();

        /**
         * 
         * Called when the activity is first created.
         */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.video_layout);
            context = this;
            path = getIntent().getExtras().getString("media");

            Log.v("arpit", "path " + path);
            mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview1);
            holder = mPreview.getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(this);
            holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        }

        private void playVideo() {
            doCleanUp();
            try {

                // Create a new media player and set the listeners
                File f = new File(path);
                // FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);

                RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(f, "r");
                // randomAccessFile.skipBytes(1024);
                FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = randomAccessFile.getFD();

                mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileDescriptor, Constant.key1.length
                        + Data.deviceID.length(), f.length());

                mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);

                // mediaController = new MediaController(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                Toast.makeText(context, "supported video was not found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }

        public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
            Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged called");
            if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "invalid video width(" + width + ") or height(" + height
                        + ")");
                return;
            }
            mIsVideoSizeKnown = true;
            mVideoWidth = width;
            mVideoHeight = height;
            if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
                startVideoPlayback();
            }
        }


        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {
            Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed called");
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated called");
            playVideo();

        }

        private void doCleanUp() {
            mVideoWidth = 0;
            mVideoHeight = 0;
            mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
            mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
        }

        private void startVideoPlayback() {
            Log.v(TAG, "startVideoPlayback");
//also tried and used the below line but nothing good 


// holder.setFixedSize(480, 800);

holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);

mMediaPlayer.start();

        }


    }
```

Comment: try [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293909/surfaceview-height-width-gets-ignored/20798009#20798009).May this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

I used TextureView instead of surface view (it allows to rotate video) and set its setScale{X|Y}() appropriately in:

```
@Override
public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int w, int h) {
    if (w > 0 && h > 0) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams l;
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        l = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.heightPixels, metrics.widthPixels);
        l.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, -1);
        float scale = (metrics.heightPixels * 1.0f) / (metrics.widthPixels * 1.0f);
        videoView.setScaleX(scale);
        videoView.setLayoutParams(l);
        Log.d(YourApp.TAG, "video size: " + mp.getVideoWidth() + "x" + mp.getVideoHeight() + " vertical scale: " + scale);
    }
}
```

Note that I have rotated my video, this is why I set scale for X.

Answer (score 1):

Hi arpit i was also working on the same devices as you have mentioned for playing video files,
 I to got the same problem while applying controls to video player (Abstract method not available).

As per my R&D on this topic i come to conclusion that the Customized android OS and the hardware of these devices are not compatible for each other as they are of very poor quality as compared to Samsung devices,
so many of methods though they are in android OS but not supported by such devices.

So i think there is no solutions for such problems, in these devices.

plz try to focus using standard devices while developing any project. this may help you a lot.

Thanks. :)